# Using callbacks to reproduce UIAlertViewController

Tags: ios, swift, callback

I want to reproduce the functionality of the UIAlertController as the class isn't very customisable. So here is what I did:

1. Create a DeleteDeckViewController that only has two buttons Yes, and No, with a callback method

   ```
   class DeleteDeckViewController: UIViewController {

       var deleteDeck : ((deleteDeck : Bool) -> ())?

       @IBAction func yesButton(sender: AnyObject) {
           deleteDeck!(deleteDeck: true)
       }

       @IBAction func noButton(sender: AnyObject) {
           deleteDeck!(deleteDeck: false)
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the main view controller when the delete button is pressed it creates a popup DeleteDeck

   ```
   func handleDelete(detailDeckView: DetailDeckView) {

       let deleteDeckViewController = DeleteDeckViewController(nibName: "DeleteDeckViewController", bundle: nil)
       let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: deleteDeckViewController, transitionStyle: .BounceDown, buttonAlignment: .Horizontal, gestureDismissal: true)
       presentViewController(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)

       deleteDeckViewController.deleteDeck(true) { () -> Void in
           print("Deck deleted")
       }
   }
   ```

What I want to do is to use a callback to tell my main view controller whether the user pressed yes or no and then do some actions depending on yes or no. Although, I don't know the correct way to do it. I've read a few articles on callbacks, but I don't know how to apply it in this situation. I've tried using delegates it's just that I would need to pass the DetailDeckView object around without it being used so that's why I thought callback would be a better choice.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: There is no such thing as `UIAlertViewController`. Do you mean the newer `UIAlertController` or the deprecated `UIAlertView`?

Comment: Sorry I meant UIAlertController let me update it!

Comment: UIAlertController should be able to do what you need. I would suggest reading through its API docs again.

Comment: But it's isn't customizable enough, as I want to customize how to looks etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `DeleteDeckViewController` you have declared the `deleteDeck` variable as a function. Therefore, when you use an instance of this class, you need to set it as a variable. Therefore you code would look more like that below (untested):

```
func handleDelete(detailDeckView: DetailDeckView) {

    let deleteDeckViewController = DeleteDeckViewController(nibName: "DeleteDeckViewController", bundle: nil)
    deleteDeckViewController.deleteDeck = myDeleteHandler
    let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: deleteDeckViewController, transitionStyle: .BounceDown, buttonAlignment: .Horizontal, gestureDismissal: true)
    presentViewController(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func myDeleteHandler(shouldDelete: Bool) {
    if shouldDelete {
        print("Delete deck")
    }
}
```

Also, in your code, rather than using `deleteDeck!` which will fail if `deleteDeck` is nil, it is better practice to use code like:

```
if let deleteDeck = self.deleteDeck {
    deleteDeck(true)
}
```

This will create a local non-Optional variable called deleteDeck, that can be assured to not contain nil.

You could build this code into `DeleteDeckViewController` to streamline further:

```
class DeleteDeckViewController: ....

    func showDialog(vc: UIViewController, completion: ((deleteDeck : Bool) -> Void)?) {
        self.deleteDeck = completion
        let popup = PopupDialog(viewController: vc, transitionStyle: .BounceDown, buttonAlignment: .Horizontal, gestureDismissal: true)
        presentViewController(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just for my understanding, would I be able to implement this using a completion handler, or would it not be possible?

Comment: Yes that would be a good option - not the completion handler for `presentViewController` though. You would have to create your own function in `DeleteDeckViewController` to show the dialog that takes a completion handler parameter, and just sets the deleteDeck property.

Comment: Would you mind adding this to your answer? it would really help